# Java applications using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, plugins, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

Would you please tell me where can I find the source code of java applications using hibernate.  I need to analyse these applications using JDT in order to extract microservices.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Search for [`"import org.hibernate" in:file`](https://github.com/search?q=%22import+org.hibernate%22+in%3Afile+&type=Code) on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you very much